# Well cloudy after heavy use?

Tags: plumbing, well, water-quality

This may be a stupid question, but we recently installed a 17k gallon pool and used our well to fill it. Our water from the well to the house is now cloudy. It doesn't taste bad, just cloudy. I am assuming this may be normal and some sediment may have been disturbed because of the constant pumping. Our water was only cloudy once before and that is when we had it installed 3 years ago.

I wanted to use a water service, but it was cost prohibitive considering how far we live from the services.

Comment: My water has cleared up. So, I am assuming it was due to the heavy use and pump running often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I stated in my comment, the water cleared up after a 4 or 5 days. It has been fine ever since.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  The community bot bumped it, probably because it doesn't have an accepted answer, so the system thinks you're still looking for a solution.  Consider accepting your own answer.  BTW, sediment would have been my guess,also.

Comment: What do you know about your aquifer? It might be worth looking into local hydrology to avoid trouble down the road.